# What stone/crystal is it?

Tags: geology, mineralogy, crystallography, crystals

I found this stone/crystal when I walked down the street few days ago.
[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 3]
[image: Pic 4]
[image: Pic 5]
[image: Pic 6]

I picked it up since it looks very different with other stones in the area,

I am really curious about what stone/crystal it is, but discovered nothing as I have zero knowledge on geology/earth science.

Therefore, I hope anyone here can help me to identify what stone it is.

TIA

Comment: if it dissolves in water=NACL,if not=quartz